# In Ruby, how can I know if a method is an attribute accessor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have the following problem:

I am renaming all instance methods for a specific class, using **alias_method_chain** in order to give them extra behavior. I get all instance methods with the following line of code:

```
self.class.instance_methods(false)
```

By doing that I get all my instance methods, but I also get the gettes and setters that I defined using attr_accessor / attr_reader / attr_writer.
What I need to do, is detect which methods returned from the previous line of code are accessor methods because I don't want to rename those.

Obviusly, I can detect if the method name has a "=" at the end, that would make it a setter, and if that exists, I can see if the getter is defined aswell, but what happens when there is only a getter defined? How can I check that? Specially considering that the attributes are not available for the class method "instance_variables" until they're initialized?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can detect if the method name has a "=" at the end, but this method could be defined manual. It doesn't mean, it is defined with attr_accessor/attr_writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may extend attr_reader... to store the methods.

```
class Object
  class << self
    attr_reader :accessors
    attr_reader :setters
    attr_reader :getters

    alias :attr_accessor_old :attr_accessor
    def attr_accessor(methname)
      (@accessors ||= [] ) << methname
      attr_accessor_old methname
    end

    alias :attr_writer_old :attr_writer
    def attr_writer(methname)
      (@setters ||= [] ) << "#{methname}=".to_sym
      attr_writer_old methname
    end

    alias :attr_reader_old :attr_reader
    def attr_reader(methname)
      (@getters ||= [] ) << methname
      attr_reader_old methname
    end

  end
end

class Test
  attr_accessor :acc
  attr_reader :read
  attr_writer :write
end
Test.instance_methods(false).each{|meth|
  puts "#{meth} is an accessor" if Test.accessors.include?(meth)
  puts "#{meth} is a setter" if Test.setters.include?(meth)
  puts "#{meth} is a getter" if Test.getters.include?(meth)
}
```

Result:

```
acc is an accessor
read is a getter
write= is a setter
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the idea, sounds like a good plan, I'll probably do that!